# programmatically change flipswitch value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried fiddling with some HTML/JS/CSS 
But got stuck on how to change the flipswich dynamically to a desired state.

CSS from here https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("innerswitchid").className = document.getElementById("innerswitchid").className + "onoffswitch-inner:before";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("innerswitchid").className = document.getElementById("innerswitchid").className + "onoffswitch-inner:after";
}
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #34A7C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span id="innerswitchid" class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
      </label>
</div>
<button onclick="on()">ON</button>
<button onclick="off()">OFF</button>
```

However that just crashes the flipswich. How can I change the flipswich dynamically to a desired state using js to change the css of the component?

Comment: `document.getElementById("innerswitchid").className += "onoffswitch-inner:before";` would do the same thing as what you have in your on() function and would be more concise and readable

Comment: What's to stop you from just toggling the checked property like so? http://jsfiddle.net/c1a0p8jn/

Comment: You can't add/remove pseudo elements like that. You need to set the pseudo-elements for two different classes in CSS (create 4 separate rules), and then swap the class name. Also notice, that `className` is a space-separated list of class names.

Comment: Yes, @BuddhistBeast is right i can do that i just have seen people fiddling with css and that it can be used for more various reasons but you can answer and i will approve.

Comment: @Teemu yes space separation is my mistake here yet it doesn't work even with a space prior for that and i have tried the js replace function and after that to append the class name yet it doesn't work either

Comment: I'm not sure what you've tried, but `onoffswitch-inner:before` is not a valid class name. You've to create rules for classes like `.onswitch` and `.offswitch`, and also for pseudo elements like `.onswitch::before` and `offswitch::before`. Then simply toggle between `onswitch` and `offswitch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your code to the following:

### HTML

```
<button id="js-btn--on">
  ON
</button>
<button id="js-btn--off">
  OFF
</button>
```

### JS

```
   document.getElementById("js-btn--on").onclick = on;
   document.getElementById("js-btn--off").onclick = off;

   function on() {
     document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked = true;

   }

   function off() {
     document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked = false;
   }
```

You can toggle the checkbox and let the CSS do what it intends to accomplish rather than mixing JS and CSS.